# Can I do math on the result of an embedded query in the parent query?

Tags: mysql, sql

Consider the query:

```
SELECT n.nid, 
    (select count(*) as count from view_log where id = n.nid) AS the_count,
    (the_count + 1) as the_bumped_count
   FROM node n
```

When I run this, I get `Unknown column 'the_count' in 'field list'`.  Is there any way around this?  It seems like `the_count` should be visible in the query and available for use, but apparently not.  BTW, I also tried `SUM(the_count, 1)`, but that also failed.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this would work as well, and only require you to count once:

```
SELECT nid, the_count, the_count+1 as the_bumped_count
FROM (
    SELECT n.nid,
        COUNT(v.*) the_count, 
    FROM node n
       LEFT JOIN view_log v on n.nid = v.id
    GROUP BY n.nid
) t
```

Or to go back to your syntax:

```
SELECT nid, the_count, the_count+1 as the_bumped_count
FROM (
    SELECT n.nid,
        (select count(*) as count from view_log where id = n.nid) AS the_count
    FROM node n
) t
```

Good luck.

Comment: The sub-query approach works best for me -- the code I posted was a simplified version of my real problem, but it adapts well to the Real Thing.  Thanks!

Comment: @JimMiller -- np, glad we could!

Answer (score 2):

you cannot use the `ALIAS` that was define on the same level you want to have a calculation on it.

```
SELECT n.nid, 
    (select count(*) as count from view_log where id = n.nid) AS the_count,
    ((select count(*) as count from view_log where id = n.nid) + 1) as the_bumped_count
   FROM node n
```

or better use subquery,

```
SELECT  nid, 
        the_count, 
        the_count + 1 AS the_bumped_count
FROM
(   
    SELECT n.nid, 
            (select count(*) as count from view_log where id = n.nid) AS the_count
    FROM node n
) s
```